# MPI communication running multiple executables

Tags: c++, mpi

I am implementing a program that should run a master-slave algorithm, and the master-slave jobs will be determined by execution parameters.
For example:

`mpirun -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 1 BioNetFit2 -a load -c parabolaA_272002678.sconf : -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 4 BioNetFit2 -t particle -p 0 -a run -c parabolaA_272002678.sconf`

In this case the master will run this part: `./BioNetFit2 -a load -c parabolaA_272002678.sconf`

And the slaves will execute this part: `./BioNetFit2 -t particle -p 0 -a run -c parabolaA_272002678.sconf`

And this is how I'm initializing the communication world:

```
   cout << "Detected BNF2mpi in Pheromones init()" << endl;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    cout << "Defined mpi environment" << endl;
    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    cout << "My rank is " << world_rank << "and I have just started." << endl;
```

My problem is that the master sends a message and the slaves never receive it, and vice-versa.

All the source code is available here: https://github.com/raqueldias/testing_rep 
This is a large program, and it was implemented first in boost-MPI by another person, my job is to convert the distributed message passing function from boost-MPI to MPI.

My first very basic question is: If I run the program in 2 parts like that, are the processes able to communicate normally by default, or I have to specify any different configuration to make them communicate?

Comment: please post the send/recieve parts in the question. It is not clear what is the cause of it. Put more code so we can check it.

Comment: Just uploaded the whole source code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this problem of the processes hanging had nothing to do with the execution of multiple programs or multiple instances in the mpirun execution.

I misunderstood the way that MPI_Iprobe works. This is how I implemented it before:

```
while (1) {
            //std::cout << "rcv loop" << std::endl;
            serializedMessage.resize(1000);
            usleep(10000);
            MPI_Status status;
            int flag = 0;

            while(!flag){
                    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status);
            }
if (flag) {
         //receive code here
           }
```

}
...

This was making the processes hang. The correct implematation that made the program work was:

```
    while (1) {
                //std::cout << "rcv loop" << std::endl;
                serializedMessage.resize(1000);
                usleep(10000);
                MPI_Status status;
                int flag = 0;

                MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, &status);

                if (flag==1) {
                  //do something here
    }

}
```